# Conditionals with multiple values in a key in a hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
cities = { 
 :birmingham => ['b31', 'b32', 'b33'],
 :walsall => ['ws1', 'ws2', 'ws3']
 }
```

I'm teaching myself Ruby and I came up with the above. I want to have an if statement:

```
if cities[:walsall] == 'ws1'
 puts "ws1 is a postcode of Walsall"
else
 puts "Your postcode was not found in the city you've typed"
end
```

Is there a way to get the above to true?

I cant find any documentation regarding the above hash.

Comment: This is a pure Ruby question, so you shouldn't have the Rails tag. Including it may cause some readers only interested Rails question to waste time and other readers who filter out Rails questions to miss your question. Also, I suggest that in future you hold off with the green checkmark for awhile, as it may discourage other, possibly better, answers, and is not nice to those still preparing answers. Many askers wait several hours before selecting an answer. There's no rush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if cities[:walsall].include? 'ws1'
```

Small advice: when you are looking for a suitable method, you can open up a console, get an object you expect should have the method you're looking for (In this case any array) and call:

```
`puts object.methods`     # In this case it would be [].methods
```

It will give you a whole list of methods available for given object. You can then get through them and check if any method name sounds good for what you need. You can then google it with `ruby <object_class> <method name>`. - This is the best way to learn new methods, and ruby offers seriously a lot of them.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!! I cant accept until 10mins. Is there a way to put this is Rails 4 where after the .include? where the user would input "ws1"?

Comment: I would strongly recommend so you start learning ruby without rails first. I know from my own experience that rails is a very bad starting point for ruby as it makes everything to seem tangled and obscure. In case of the question you just asked 0 it is very unclear for me whether those cities are hashes or ActiveRecord objects. is it part of the controller? How does user input anything - through some kind of form?

Comment: The hash would go in a controller, the I'd use instance variables in the views. I would use the if statements in the views but at the and of ".include", there would be an input field so after the user hits "ok" or "next", the if statement would execute

Comment: @Sylar - do you want it to happen server-side or client-side. As to the question `is it possible` - it definitively is. From your description it seems like a client-side stuff, and hence you need to use javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

Like BroiSatse indicated, `Array` has method `include?` which can be used to check for presence of an element. Actually all `Enumerable` types in Ruby have, so `Hash` and `Set` also support `include?`.

For the example you use, arrays are just fine. Note that if lists are large, then checking for presence of an element could become rather expensive. For such use cases, `Set` is much more suitable:

```
Set.new(['b31', 'b32', 'b33']).include?('b32') # true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if cities.values[1].include?('ws1')
   puts "ws1 is a postcode of Walsall"
 else
   puts "Your postcode was not found in the city you've typed"
 end
#=> ws1 is a postcode of Walsall
```

Every Hash object has two methods: `keys` and `values`. The keys method returns an array of all the `keys` in the Hash. Similarly `values` returns an array of just the `values`.

**For E.g**

```
restaurant_menu = { "Ramen" => 3, "Dal Makhani" => 4, "Coffee" => 2 }
restaurant_menu.keys
=> ["Ramen", "Dal Makhani", "Coffee"]
```